# sort data in ascending order by the sum of the columns

Tags: r

I have a dataframe that looks similar to this:

```
v1 v2 v3 v4 v5 v6
.. .. .. .. .. ..
.. .. .. .. .. ..
```

With 100 rows. I want to sort my data into ascending order by the `sum` of individuals in `col` `v5` and `v6`.

I have tried using this code but to no avail:

```
datatestt <- rowSums(df(V5, V6))
```

The code above gives me an error, how-else can I sort my data?

Comment: For the `rowSums`, it should be `rowSums(df[c("v5", "v6")])`, assuming `v5` and `v6` are the column names.  The actual question is not clear though.  If you can show a small reproducible example and expected output, would be helpful (Perhaps `df[order(rowSums(df[c("v5", "v6")])),]`)

Answer (score 0):

If we want to `order` based on the `rowSums` of subset of columns, subset the columns `df[c("v5", "v6")]`, apply `rowSums` and `order` the `vector` to create an index ('i1') which can used in `i` for ordering the rows

```
i1 <- order(rowSums(df[c("v5", "v6")]))
dfnew <- df[i1, ]
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
df %>%
    arrange(select(., v5, v6) %>%
                 reduce(`+`))
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(1:20, 6 * 10, replace = TRUE), 
      ncol = 6, dimnames = list(NULL, paste0("v", 1:6))))
```

Comment: I tried by using this. but it is showing "Error in rowSums(Ques3_4[c("V5", "V6", "V7")]) : 'x' must be numeric"

Comment: @Roy  then your columns are  not numeric.  Please check the `str(df)` and change it to numeric.  I showed a reproducible example that works i.e. `Ques3_4[c("V5", "V6", "V7")] <- lapply(Ques3_4[c("V5", "V6", "V7")], function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))`  the `as.character` is used if the columns are factors

Comment: library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
df %>%
    arrange(select(., v5, v6) %>%
                 reduce(`+`))                                                                                            I used that, so my data is orderly arranged only? or after rowsome, then arranged orderly? Thank you for your prompt response.

Comment: @Roy `+` does the row wise sum of those columnss and is used within `arrange` to arrange the rows

Comment: yes. I got the result, but the data is arranged according to descending order. But I want to get ascending order.

Comment: @Roy I get the result in the same way (ascending is by default - so not sure how you get that outpuut) as in the `rowSums`.  if you want to have descending, it should be specified `arrange(desc(select(., v5, v6) %>% reduce(`+`)))`